# pre-update check not available

Tags: update

Site is on Joomla 3.10.11 and Update Channel is on Joomla Next but I get the messages that there is no update available and the site is on the newest version. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

welcome!

1. Go to **Components → Joomla Update**. (It should say no updates
   found. If it doesn’t, update Joomla to the latest version (must be
   3.10.x) Click on the Options button at the top right corner.
2. Select Joomla Next from the drop-down for Update Channel.

[image]

3. Click Save & Close. You will then see the latest Joomla! version and the URL for the update package. Also, Joomla will show you the requirements for Joomla 4.

**Is important you kown this is a migration and not a normal update. I strongly advice follow this guide for you can do the task successful (at least with the less problems you can get)** https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_3.x_to_4.x_Step_by_Step_Migration

Comment: Thanks! Problem was indeed that Update Sites > Joomla! Core was not activated.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin pages go to the Extension Manager and the Update Sites option and check that the Joomla core entries are both Published.
[image]

Then click on the Rebuild button.

Next select the Manage menu item and press the Refresh Cache button.
[image]

Then check for the Joomla update again.

There is a couple of previous answers from a few years back that provide a additional list of steps to follow if it is still not working for you.